# Issue with fine position for a SVG file into HTML page (SVG made by Inkscape command line)

Tags: html, css, svg

From [this link](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL_v14/html_fr/CommandLine-Export.html), I generate a SVG file from a Postscript (itself made by latex) :

```
inkscape example.ps --export-plain-svg example.svg
```

`example.ps` comes from example.tex below :

```
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-2.5)(6,2.5)
\rput(-4,1.5){light\,(1\,:\,yes,\,0\,:\,no)}
\rput(-4,-0.5){noise\,(1\,:\,yes,\,0\,:\,no)}
\rput(5,1.5){eyes\,(0\,:\,closed,\,1\,:\,opened)}
\rput(5,-0.5){voice\,(00\,:\,snore,\,01\,:\,laugh,\,10:\,growl,\,11:\,cry)}
\rput(0,0){Robot toy module}

\psframe(-1.5,-2)(1.5,2)

\psline{->}(-1.5,1)(-4,1)
\psline{->}(-1.5,-1)(-4,-1)
\psline{->}(1.5,1)(4,1)
\psline{->}(1.5,-1)(4,-1)
\psline{-}(2.5,-1.2)(2.9,-0.8)
\rput(2.7,-1.4){2}

\psline{-}(-0.2,-2)(0,-1.7)
\psline{-}(0.2,-2)(0,-1.7)
\psline{-}(0,-2)(0,-2.4)
\rput(0,-2.6){H}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Now I would like to include into a HTML page with a fine position, i.e at the top of parent container.

Unfortunately, I have troubles to adjust the parameters of position from the SVG file into HTML ; for example, I put into HTML page :

```
<object data="example.svg" width="700 " height="400 " type="image/svg+xml">
```

and "`example.svg`" (just created vith inkscape) contains :

```
viewBox="0 0 743.75 1052.5"
   height="1052.5"
   width="743.75"
```

But the result (visible on [this link](http://beulu.com/last/index3.html)) is not good, since SVG is too small.

The SVG file is located on  [the following link](http://beulu.com/last/example.svg).

I took `width="700 " height="400` for `<object>` because it would be, like for a standard image into `<img> tag`,  a fine size (and so position) for the SVG into HTML page.

Maybe this problem comes from width and height offsets for SVG "example.svg" file (seen when I visualize it directly in browser : [check here](http://beulu.com/last/example.svg) )

I tried to set 700 and 400 in viewBox and also for height width :

```
viewBox="0 0 700 400"
height="400"
width="700"
```

The result is visible [here](http://beulu.com/last/index5.html). For width, it may be acceptable but I have still this large vertical offset (I mean blank space) with the top "title" ("Coding > Robot module").

Is there a general rule to apply for positioning a SVG file without offset. (or at least with a small offset like with an image).

PS: I would like to keep the `<object> tag` to include the SVG into HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the SVG generated by LaTeX is for the whole page, and the `viewBox` it sets represents the page.

To get the diagram in the middle of the page to scale and fit whatever size you want it to, you need to update the `viewBox` so that it reflexts the bounding box of (just) your diagram.

So it turns out that the appropriate viewBox to use is approximately:

```
viewBox="134 174 489 168"
```

If you set it to that (and update your `width` and `height`) you will end up with an SVG that behaves as you want.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="134 174 489 168"
   height="168"
   width="489"
   xml:space="preserve"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg2"><metadata
     id="metadata8"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
         rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
     id="defs6" /><g
     transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,0,1052.5)"
     id="g10"><g
       transform="scale(0.1,0.1)"
       id="g12"><g
         transform="scale(10,10)"
         id="g14"><text
           id="text16"
           style="font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:9.96263981px;font-family:CMR10;-inkscape-font-specification:CMR10;writing-mode:lr-tb;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,108.974,686.3)"><tspan
             id="tspan18"
             y="0"
             x="0 2.7596512 5.5193024 10.559301 15.839153 21.359074 25.199078 31.798918 36.238419 41.278271 45.718269 49.678268 53.997841 60.597839 65.037338 70.557343 75.597343">light(1:yes,0:no)</tspan><tspan
             id="tspan20"
             y="56.6926"
             x="-0.96015602 4.559844 9.599843 12.359494 16.319492 22.319571 26.159575 32.759415 37.198917 42.238766 46.678768 50.638767 54.958336 61.678257 66.11776 71.637756 76.677757">noise(1:yes,0:no)</tspan><tspan
             id="tspan22"
             y="0"
             x="239.63785 244.07784 249.11792 253.55791 259.07809 262.91806 269.51791 273.9574 278.3974 281.15704 286.19702 290.15704 294.59705 300.11703 304.43674 311.15668 315.47626 320.51627 326.27628 330.71631 336.23633 340.67636 346.19638">eyes(0:closed,1:opened)</tspan><tspan
             id="tspan24"
             y="56.6926"
             x="200.39804 205.43788 210.47787 213.23752 217.67751 223.67735 227.51735 232.55736 239.15742 243.59691 247.55693 253.07692 258.11691 262.07693 266.51691 270.8364 275.8764 282.35632 286.79581 289.55545 294.59546 300.11545 305.15546 310.67545 315.11502 320.15503 325.19504 329.51471 334.55472 338.51471 343.31473 350.51474 353.27438 357.47418 362.51419 367.5542 371.87387 376.31387 380.27386 385.55386">voice(00:snore,01:laugh,10:growl,11:cry)</tspan><tspan
             id="tspan26"
             y="42.5196"
             x="113.50584 120.82584 125.86586 131.62576 136.66576 143.74568 147.58568 152.38553 160.90544 169.18546 174.46559 179.98558 185.50557 188.26523">Robottoymodule</tspan></text>
</g><path
         id="path28"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:7.97010994;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 2199.59,6461.8 0,562.94 842.42,0 0,-1125.88 -842.42,0 0,562.94 z" /><path
         id="path30"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="m 1530.18,6760.71 -43.24,-15.44 43.24,-15.45 -17.29,15.45" /><path
         id="path32"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:7.97010994;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 2195.6,6745.27 -682.71,0" /><path
         id="path34"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="m 1530.18,6193.78 -43.24,-15.44 43.24,-15.45 -17.29,15.45" /><path
         id="path36"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:7.97010994;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 2195.6,6178.34 -682.71,0" /><path
         id="path38"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="m 3711.42,6729.82 43.24,15.45 -43.24,15.44 17.29,-15.44" /><path
         id="path40"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:7.97010994;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 3046,6745.27 682.71,0" /><path
         id="path42"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="m 3711.42,6162.89 43.24,15.45 -43.24,15.44 17.29,-15.44" /><path
         id="path44"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:7.97010994;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 3046,6178.34 682.71,0" /><path
         id="path46"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:7.97010994;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 3329.46,6121.64 113.38,113.39" /><g
         transform="scale(10,10)"
         id="g48"><text
           id="text50"
           style="font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:9.96263981px;font-family:CMR10;-inkscape-font-specification:CMR10;writing-mode:lr-tb;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,336.095,603.375)"><tspan
             id="tspan52"
             y="0"
             x="0">2</tspan></text>
</g><path
         id="path54"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:7.97010994;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 2564.11,5894.87 56.69,85.04" /><path
         id="path56"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:7.97010994;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 2677.49,5894.87 -56.69,85.04" /><path
         id="path58"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:7.97010994;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m 2620.8,5894.87 0,-113.38" /><g
         transform="scale(10,10)"
         id="g60"><text
           id="text62"
           style="font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:9.96263981px;font-family:CMR10;-inkscape-font-specification:CMR10;writing-mode:lr-tb;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,258.36,569.119)"><tspan
             id="tspan64"
             y="0"
             x="0">H</tspan><tspan
             id="tspan66"
             y="429.819"
             x="44.7598">1</tspan></text>
</g></g></g></svg>
```

If you need your diagram to scale and fit its parent container. Set both width and height to "100%".

Comment: PaulLeBeau: thanks ! how do you compute or get the values "134 174" ?

Comment: Often you can call `getBBox()` function on the element. But in this case LaTeX is adding varied transforms to the surrounding groups, so you can't use the results from `getBBox()` directly.  The simple answer is, experimentation. I systematically adjusted the values until I found the right values.